# Separate TouchPhase.Began and TouchPhase.Moved

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In one of my Android applications (Made with Unity), I would like to move the camera by scrolling with finger on the screen and simultaneously not detect hit, when I touch on any object during scrolling. My problem is that when I want to scroll down the camera with my finger, it firstly also detects hits with the objects. I have one script which is attached to Main Camera.
Here's the code for better understanding.

```
//Update function for scrolling and detecting touch. 
//Do not want to detect touch on objects when scrolling.
void Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

        checkTouch(Input.GetTouch(0).position);

    }
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

        transform.Translate(0, -touchDeltaPosition.y * Time.deltaTime, 0);

        transform.position = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, -30, 0), -10);

    }
}
void checkTouch(Vector3 pos){
    Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
    Vector2 touchpos = new Vector2 (wp.x, wp.y);
    hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint (touchpos);

    if (hit) {
        //Debug.Log (hit.transform.gameObject.name);
        //hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage ("Clicked", null, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);


        if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "item"){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try use something like this

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount <= 0)
        return;

    bool lMove = false;

    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Debug.Log("Touch phase = Moved");
        lMove = true;

        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
        transform.Translate(0, -touchDeltaPosition.y * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, -30, 0), -10);
    }
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        Debug.Log("Touch phase = Ended");
        if (!lMove)
        {
            //onClick
            checkTouch(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I've found one problem. When I lift up my finger after scrolling and when my finger is over any object at that moment, it acts as if I have touched it, but I've just released a finger. Dunno how to solve it.

Comment: Do you talk about map scrolling? Maybe you did not observe the flag lMove in code above?

Comment: I mean that when I'm scrolling and end up with my finger over some touchable object, it registers a touch(I haven't touched it, just released a finger after scrolling). However, I was able to solve it by putting small time break after each release of finger.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LineDirDetector: MonoBehaviour {

    public Text texto01;

    //inside class
    Vector2 firstPressPos;
    Vector2 secondPressPos;
    Vector2 currentSwipe;

    void Update()

    {
        Swipe();
    }

    public void Swipe() {
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {
            Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                //save began touch 2d point
                firstPressPos = new Vector2(t.position.x, t.position.y);
            }
            if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                //save ended touch 2d point
                secondPressPos = new Vector2(t.position.x, t.position.y);

                //create vector from the two points
                currentSwipe = new Vector3(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);

                //normalize the 2d vector
                currentSwipe.Normalize();

                //swipe upwards
                if (currentSwipe.y > 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5 f) {
                    Debug.Log("up swipe");
                    texto01.text = "ARRIBA";

                }
                //swipe down
                if (currentSwipe.y < 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5 f) {
                    Debug.Log("down swipe");
                    texto01.text = "ABAJO";

                }
                //swipe left
                if (currentSwipe.x < 0 && currentSwipe.y > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.y < 0.5 f) {
                    Debug.Log("left swipe");
                    texto01.text = "IZQUIERDA";

                }
                //swipe right
                if (currentSwipe.x > 0 && currentSwipe.y > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.y < 0.5 f) {
                    Debug.Log("right swipe");
                    texto01.text = "DERECHA";
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please include some explanation with this code?